# Why does this create an infinite render loop with React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to render beer names as H1 elements in a alphabetical sorted order and I'm new to React Hooks but this seems to cause a re-render loop

The Beer component is passed an array of beers as props from the Home component which utilises the useEffect Hook which I suspect may be the culprit although I'm not sure.

```
const Beer = ({ beer }) => {
  const [beers, setBeers] = useState([]);
  let rendered;
  if (beer === undefined) {
    rendered = <Spinner />;
  } else {
    rendered = beer.map(beer => beer.name);
    setBeers(rendered.sort());
    rendered = beers.map(beer => <h1>{beer}</h1>);
  }

  return <div>{rendered}</div>;
};

const Home = () => {
  const [beers, setBeers] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const getBeers = async () => {
      const beerData = await fetch('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers');
      const beers = await beerData.json();
      console.log(beers);
      setBeers(beers);
    };
    getBeers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Punk Beers</h1>
      <Beer beer={beers} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I expect there to be a rendered list of H1 elements but this produces an endless loop of renders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `setBeers` inside of `Beer` React will re-render the component (i.e. re-execute the function) with the updated value being provided for the `beers` state variable.

You generally do not need to copy props into state like this. If you have a component that performs an expensive operation on props before displaying, you may want to [use memoization to cache the result](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-memoize-calculations).

In this case, simply sorting `beers` isn't expensive unless your array is thousands and thousands of items long, so no optimization is necessary.

```js
const Beer = ({ beers }) => (
  beers ? (
    [...beers].sort().map((beer, index) => 
      <h1 key={index}>{beer}</h1>
    )
  ) : (
    <Spinner />
  )
)

const Home = () => {
  const [beers, setBeers] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const getBeers = async () => {
      const beerData = await fetch('https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers');
      const beers = await beerData.json();
      console.log(beers);
      setBeers(beers);
    };
    getBeers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Punk Beers</h1>
      <Beer beers={beers} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I understand that and I appreciate your answer but without calling `setBeers`, how is it best to update state and render the names?

Comment: When the props change the component will be re-rendered. `Beer` doesn't need any local state.

Comment: Got it, that makes perfect sense. Your answer got more elaborate a few times and I appreciate it, thank you.